# Are there encryption systems that are both homomorphic and commutative?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, reference-request, commutative-encryption

If so, which ones are?

If not, is it known whether or not these are mutually exclusive?

Is there a page that exhaustively lists encryption systems and properties such as these? I could not find a resource to help me find these answers on my own.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\Enc}{\operatorname{Enc}}$
Actually, Pohlig-Hellman exhibits a homomorphism and commutativity.

For the commutativity, see [poncho's answer on your other question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51912/23623).

The homomorphism goes as follows
(it is really just plain multiplication, not unlike what is possible with textbook RSA):
$$\Enc(m_1)\cdot\Enc(m_2)=m_1^a\cdot m_2^a=(m_1m_2)^a=\Enc(m_1m_2)\pmod p$$